# PHP/MYSQL get tomorrow records from

Tags: php, codeigniter, mysqli, timestamp, strtotime

I have a `varchar` field contain a `timestamp` value, i want to get the tomorrow records.

This is my code as you can see:

```
$tomorrow = strtotime("1+ day");
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_accomplish_date > $tomorrow
```

but the query is incorrect

thanks for the help in advance

Comment: note + ,should be `$tomorrow = strtotime("+1 day");`

Answer (score 1):

**Should be like this :**

```
$tomorrow = strtotime("+1 day");

/* this will select all record before tomorrow*/
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_accomplish_date < $tomorrow;

/* this will select all record after tomorrow*/
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_accomplish_date > $tomorrow;
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE task_accomplish_date >  NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this all in the MySQL query

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `tasks` 
    WHERE DATE(`task_accomplish_date`) = DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

That converts your `task_accomplish_date` into a date value and looks for records where that date is equal to today + 1 day (tomorrow).  That does not give you records from 2 days from today or beyond, just tomorrow.  If you want tomorrow and all records beyond tomorrow you would use

```
SELECT * 
    FROM `tasks` 
    WHERE DATE(`task_accomplish_date`) >= DATE(NOW() + INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

If you are storing a timestamp, these only care about the date part of the timestamp, not about the time part of the timestamp.  If you care about the time part as well you can remove `DATE()` from both sides of the `=` in the `WHERE` clause

Comment: $query = array("task_accomplish_date <=" => strtotime("today midnight")); i'm using Codeigniter